# Does JUnit have an disabled attribute/element for test cases?

Tags: xml, parsing, testing, junit

I'm creating a a module that converts test results into JUnit XML format.

This [link](http://help.catchsoftware.com/display/ET/JUnit+Format) has lots of good information on standard formats like errors, failures etc...

I couldn't find anything on disabled test cases, is there a way to signify a disabled test case?

Comment: You don't want to execute a particular test case, is it what you want?

Comment: I'm not executing test cases. I'm converting test results from one format to JUnit XML Format. The original result has disabled information. I want to display this on JUnit XML Format such that applications can understand the JUnit Format

Answer (score 0):

I think the best fitting option is `<skipped />`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid using skip because skip and disable can have different connotations.